# Editing the cooldowns of spells and spell like effects

Tags: azerothcore

I am trying to reduce the cooldown on the hearthstone and inscription research spell-like effects. I have identified the hearthstone item template and imported the hearthstone spell into `spell_dbc`. I have set the spell category cooldown to 1 second, but I am experiencing a strange issue. On use, the hearthstone is set to a 30-minute cooldown and not useable during this cooldown, but on logging out and logging back in, the correct cooldown is displayed and the item is useable once the cooldown has expired. I suspect that the client is tracking the cooldown of the hearthstone independently of the server. But I have no clue where to begin looking to fix this. Has anybody successfully made a change to spell cooldowns, and would you be willing to point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to delete the client cache.

Answer (score 2):

Not a solution to your problem, but I'm pretty sure that what you are experiencing is actually an intended behavior to discourage hacking.

I think what is really going on is your login credentials are being used to create a secret that is then passed into the rest of their program, which is then used as a reference point for debugging.

Because they know the intended behavior of their own game, they can check to see if the results of arguments sent from your machine are within expected parameters.

And because your modifications fall outside of those parameters, what the developers decided to do was to change the cooldown to something sufficiently annoying to detect who keeps on manually logging out and logging back in again.

I studied programming in college, and I'm telling you that if you know enough to change the cooldowns locally, you should try doing something more productive.  Either find another game to play at the same time, or just do something completely different from gaming altogether.

Hope somebody double checks what I have said here for accuracy, because I am curious to know if I am correct about my assessment.

Comment: dwpontius, I am configuring the spell on the game server to have a lower cooldown, but I believe that the issue is that it's not modified on the client. Once I relog the client gets the spell cooldowns from the server and displays correctly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).